# Copied a tutorial from mapbox with missing variable and it won't run

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android

I've been following a step by step tutorial trying to create a map using Mapbox and Android Studio using the 'Tracking Device Location on Android" tutorial but have run into a problem that doesn't seem to be outlined on Mapbox.
In the 'Listen to Updates' section of the tutorial, on line 176 of the code it reads:

`Toast.makeText(activity, String.format(activity.getString(R.string.new_location)`

new_location  shows up in red and has not been defined beforehand. Does anyone know how to fix this?

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening/#listen-to-location-updates

Comment: I tried that already and it gave this message: format string 'new_location' is not a valid format string so should not be passed as  String. format

Comment: java basics ... find out how first string of `String.Format()` with 3 strings should looks like

Comment: You should probably report this as a bug in the tutorial to Mapbox, seems like they forgot to tell you to get the strings they used: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/blob/33620d29e2db98879fcd61e0dac3c867236b1876/MapboxAndroidDemo/src/main/res/values/activity_strings.xml#L46

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get it running, you would have to follow Ryan's advice (comment) and add the string he has highlighted from Mapbox' activity_strings.xml into your strings.xml.

```
<string name="new_location">New lat: %1$s New longitude: %2$s</string>
```

%1$s will be populated with the first parameter you pass and %2$s with second parameter you pass in

```
String.format(activity.getString(R.string.new_location),
String.valueOf(result.getLastLocation().getLatitude()), 
String.valueOf(result.getLastLocation().getLongitude()))
```